# Building my own linked list; how to make the linking only change through the list itself?

Tags: c#, access-control

I'm prepping for interviews/whiteboard questions, and I'm building some data structures from scratch for practice. For a doubly-linked list, I'm trying to make the Links themselves gettable by the user, but only settable through the LinkedList itself. What is the best practice for how to do this? The scratch code below is what I have right now (I haven't tested or done much implementation here, not seeking help on that part), but I'd like to remove the public set function of the Next and Previous for the Link while still being able to have my LinkedList set them.

```
public class MyLink<T>
{
    public MyLink<T> Next { get; set; }
    public MyLink<T> Previous { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
public class MyLinkedList<T>
{
    public MyLink<T> Head
    {
        get
        {
            return Head;
        }
        set
        {
            value.Next = Head.Next;
            value.Previous = Head.Previous;
            Head.Next.Previous = value;
            Tail.Next = value;
            Head = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make `set` private?

Comment: Having it as private or protected prevents even the LinkedList class from accessing it

Comment: That doesn't sound right; if the defining class can't access it, what can?

Comment: Does this kind of thing still get asked as interviews?  For languages (like C#) that have had things like List/HashSet/Dictionary etc as standard libraries for nearly 20 years, shouldn't the interviewer be asking how you would use them, rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The Link and LinkedList are two separate classes; the LinkedList is a collection of the Links. So the Link could call its private and protected members, but the LinkedList cannot. Though I just remember the 'internal' level of access which I think solves this problem, letting other classes in the same assembly access it

Comment: The .NET generic LinkedList class does that. You could [take a look at the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs).

Comment: @Neil Seems like a valuable filter for identifying unsuitable employers.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer; using the 'internal' access keyword solves this